# jQuery is not defined, Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, adal

I am using microsoft adal for auth in my electron app. Nowhere in my app using jQuery, but when I try to logout, [I get this Error in my app console]

[image]

```
const redirectTo = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.Adal.TenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${authContext.config.postLogoutRedirectUri}`;

const logout = () => {
    authContext.logOut();
    redirect(redirectTo, '/');    
};
```

*authContext file*

```
export const adalConfig = {
  clientId: config.Adal.ClientID,
  tenant: config.Adal.TenantID,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  redirectUri: config.Adal.RedirectURI,
  postLogoutRedirectUri: loginUrl
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);
```

The app gets stuck at 'Hang on a moment while we sign you out.'

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm experiencing exactly the same issue while using a Microsoft identity provider with Electron.  The app gets stuck at "Hang on a moment while we sign you out."

Comment: unfortunately not, I had to fork the msal library and then make a few changes in how auth works.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to search the key words `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` with `Electron` for your issue, you will get many solutions to fix it.

The frequently-used solutions are as below.

1. If you load jQuery library like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>`, please use `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')</script>` instead of it in Electron when you installed jQuery via `npm install --save jquery`.
2. Change `nodeIntegration: true` to `nodeIntegration: false` to disable Node.js in the `BrowserWindow` instance.
3. Replace the beginning content of jQuery as below as the static resource asset in Election with `!function(a,b){b(a)}`.

   ```
   // The beginning content need to be replaced
   !function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}
   ```

Comment: Like I said, I am not using jQuery anywhere in my app, so why am I getting this error? Also this error doesn't occur while running in the browser.

Comment: Apparently one of your project's dependencies does use jquery.

Comment: @getnot try with 'nodeIntegration: false' for window creation. its mentioned here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron